# Is the following the correct implementation of VGG network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, convolution

As exercise I am implementing few fundamental networks.
Specifically right now I am implementing [VGG](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf)

The code I've got at the moment is the following:

class MyVGG(nn.Module):

```
def __init__(self):
    super(MyVGG, self).__init__()
    self.arch = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3, 64, 3,padding=1),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3,padding=1),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3,padding=1),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 3,padding=1),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3,padding=1),
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 3,padding=1),
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2),
        nn.Flatten(0, 2),
        nn.Linear(512*196, 4096),
        nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
        nn.Linear(4096, 1000),
        nn.Softmax(dim=0)
    )

def forward(self, x):
    return self.arch(x)
```

This is supposed to replicate architecture A in the following table (taken from the paper above).

With a random tensor $3 \times 224 \times 224$ it does not crash, but I haven't trained on anything yet.

Can anyone confirm if this implementation is correct?

[image]